# How can I learn about the famous patent cases at USPTO?

Tags: intellectual-property

I need information about the famous cases in 2019 at USPTO about the patent cases.

Comment: What is a "famous case in 2019"?

Answer (score 1):

See the two most popular sites that cover current affairs in patents - [patentlyo](https://patentlyo.com/) and [ipwatchdog](https://www.ipwatchdog.com/). A law firm has a blog [Federal Circuit IP Blog](https://www.finnegan.com/en/insights/blogs/federal-circuit-ip/index.html)  that covers the Federal Circuit, the court that handles all patent case appeals.

---

.